# How to join two data object in one data frame in R?

Tags: r, join

I am trying to join two data objects: Death and Disability. Inside of the object is time, mean value and CI for each time point.

```
Death <- data.frame(t=time, Diff_de_mean, Diff_de_list_ci_mean)
 
Disability <- data.frame(t=time, Diff_dis_mean, Diff_dis_list_ci_mean)`
```

When I use function "full_join"
`df <- full_joint(Death, Disability)`

I get a table only with missing (NA) values for the mean value of the Disability variable but I get the CI for this value.
The question is, how should I join these two objects that I get also mean value?

Thank you!
[Showed in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuFc0.png)

I tried `full_join` function

Comment: Hi @Lena, could you please share your data using `dput()`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten I attached the figure

Comment: I mean share your two data frames `dput(Death)` and `dput(Disability)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your two dataframes, I suggest the following code should work based on the image you showed:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(Death, Disability, by = "time")
```

This will join the two data frames based on the `time`.